# Pandas Split 9GB CSV into 2 5GB CSVs

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas

I have a 9GB CSV and need to split it into 2 5GB CSVs.
I started out doing this:

```
for i, chunk in enumerate(pd.read_csv('csv_big_file2.csv',chunksize=100000)):
    chunk.drop('Unnamed: 0',axis=1,inplace=True)
    chunk.to_csv('chunk{}.csv'.format(i),index=False)
```

What I need to do is somehow tell pandas to write the chunk to a CSV until that CSV reaches a size of 6,250,000,000 (or a filesize of 5GB) then start a new CSV file with the rest of the data (without starting again from the beginning of the data from the big CSV file).

Can this be done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you mean 6 billion records or 6 million?

Comment: Billion, if my math is correct from the data I looked at.

Comment: But if it's easier to go by file size, that will work for me  as well.

Comment: You're out of luck. Pandas can't hold that much in memory.

Comment: It would hold the memory of the chunk only until it writes it to CSV. It would only read the size of the file somehow and determine if that size meets a threshold. I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: Does the order of the rows matter?  Does it have to be first half to one file and second half to the other file?  Or can it be that half gets to one file and half to the other regardless of where the rows came from?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is a little messy. But this should split the data based on the ~6 billion row threshold you mentioned.

```
import pandas as pd  
from __future__ import division

numrows = 6250000000 #number of rows threshold to be 5 GB
count = 0 #keep track of chunks
chunkrows = 100000 #read 100k rows at a time
df = pd.read_csv('csv_big_file2.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=chunkrows) 
for chunk in df: #for each 100k rows
    if count <= numrows/chunkrows: #if 5GB threshold has not been reached 
        outname = "csv_big_file2_1stHalf.csv"
    else:
        outname = "csv_big_file2_2ndHalf.csv"
    #append each output to same csv, using no header
    chunk.to_csv(outname, mode='a', header=None, index=None)
    count+=1
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the following, though: if count <= numrows/chunkrows...shouldn't it be if count*chunkrows <= numrows?

Comment: @DanceParty2 I think they are both the same. count*chunkrows <= numrows is probably more clear though

Comment: @DanceParty2 First of all you multiply by 0 at the start of iterations. He using __future__ stuff. Anyway I added my own dividers like this and it works: 
`for chunk in file:
    if count <= 30:
        outname = 'csv_big_file_1.csv'
    elif count <= 60:
 outname = 'csv_big_file_2.csv'
    elif count <= 90:
 outname = 'csv_big_file_3.csv'
    elif count <= 120:
 outname = 'csv_big_file_4.csv'
    else:
 outname = 'csv_big_file_5.csv'`

Answer (score 1):

Library dask could be helpful. You can find documentation here: http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-create.html

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

```
for i, chunk in enumerate(pd.read_csv('csv_big_file2.csv',chunksize=312500)):
    if i<11:
        chunk.to_csv(file_name, chunksize = 312500)
    else 
        chunk.to_csv(file_name_2, chunksize = 312500)
```